# How to handle a bib source with no author?

Tags: citations, authorship, citation-style, latex

I am writing a paper in English and have a couple of sources that have no author. In German there would be the abbreviation `o.V.` standing for `ohne Verfasser` which translates to `no author` in those cases.

How is this handled in English papers? Would an appropriate translation be `n.a.` standing for `no author`? Is there a way in Latex to automatically put something in place by just providing a bib entry without an author?

Instead of:

```
@online{cloud-ide04,
    author = {n.a.},
    title = {codeanywhere},
    publisher = {Codeanywhere, Inc.},
    urldate = {2018-03-26},
    url = {https://codeanywhere.com/}
}
```

Rather do:

```
@online{cloud-ide04,
    title = {codeanywhere},
    publisher = {Codeanywhere, Inc.},
    urldate = {2018-03-26},
    url = {https://codeanywhere.com/}
}
```

Comment: How about Anon. or Anonymous?

Comment: @astronat Well, I personally wouldn't mind doing that, but is there an existing APA rule or something?

Comment: As far as APA goes I have no idea. However, if you want to omit the author field in the Bibtex entry entirely I think you can use the `@misc` citation instead of `@online` as you have posted here (have a look for similar on TeX SE if that is really what you want to do). Also n/a is usually taken to stand for "not applicable" so I would avoid using that.

Comment: Nothing changed visually when changing from `@online` to `@misc`.

Comment: But anyway, seems in English there is no real placeholder for a not existing person within a bibliography. Instead the first thing might just be the title of the source instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern Language Association (8) dictates that when one piece of information is missing from a citation, one simply skips that piece of information within the citation.

For example, if I published a book called "Dogs", the final citation would start:

> Fey, Mercurial. *Dogs*.

If I had published it without an authors name, the citation would instead start:

> *Dogs*.

Both citations would then continue with editors, volumes, and publishers.

Comment: If doing this with a bib file, it can be good to provide a sorting key to avoid warnings about missing fields.